# Scroll vertical dynamically in tabPage control

Tags: vb.net, scrollbar, tabpage

In my relatively simple project I have a two page tabControl. tabPage2 consists of dynamically created pictureBoxes (thumbnails, pic_XXX). tabPage2 is of fixed size, with AutoScroll enabled.

On tabPage1, among other things, I can search for a given name (pic_XXX). When I switch to tabPage2 I'd like it to be scrolled, so the row in which pic_XXX is, is visible. Manually scrolling in tabPage2 is working.

I'm struggling to dynamically scroll tabPage2 to accomplish this. The following solution throws an exception:

```
Dim pos As Point = tabPage2.Controls.Item("pic_" & imgNum).Location
tabPage2.VerticalScroll.Value = pos.Y
tabPage2.refresh()
```

I run out of ideas!?

Comment: Generally, you would use the `tabPage2.ScrollControlIntoView(...)` method.

Comment: @LartTech it works. I had check it with different ways to determine the image in question (search box, keyboard shortcuts and navigation buttons).
Thanks very much!

How do I accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So how to scroll the specified child control into view on an auto-scroll enabled control?

> You should use method **[.ScrollControlIntoView( [Control] )](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scrollcontrolintoview(v=vs.110).aspx)**

```
tabPage2.ScrollControlIntoView(tabPage2.Controls.Item("pic_" & imgNum) )
```

---

Answer for your question:

```
Dim pos As Point = tabPage2.Controls.Item("pic_" & imgNum).Location 
tabPage2.VerticalScroll.Maximum = tabPage2.Height
tabPage2.VerticalScroll.Value = pos.Y
tabPage2.PerformLayout()
```

> You have to call **[.PerformLayout()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8aw0sd8.aspx#Y342)** to make the scrolling control update.

Comment: Thanks @Ibn Adam, but your solution throws an exception (tabPage2.AutoScroll=true; tabPage2.verticalScroll.Maximum=100)
    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
      HResult=0x80131502
      Message=Value of '215' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.
    Parameter name: Value

Comment: @user3560520 : No, that's _your_ solution throwing an exception, telling you that you are trying to scroll farther than what's possible.

Comment: Ibn Adam and @Visual Vincent sorry I misspoke: I should have said "The suggested answer by Ibn Adam doesn't solve the problem." (I editied/clarified the question). 
The problem is that VerticalScroll.Maximum value cannot be changed for tabPage with AutoScroll enabled.

Comment: @user3560520 : Did you try LarsTech's suggestion?

Comment: @user3560520 It does work.  But we don't know "where" you are calling that code.

Comment: @LarsTech 1. on page1 I determine foundImgNum; 2. call tabAutoScroll(tabPage2,foundImgNum); 3. Manually select tabPage2
As I was tidying up the code to post-it, I accidentally corrected something and it appears it works now.
I have to check and let you know.
Public Sub tabAutoScroll(tPage As TabPage, imgNum As Integer)
  Dim pos As Point = tPage.Controls.Item("pic_" & imgNum).Location
  tPage.ScrollControlIntoView(tPage.Controls.Item("pic_" & imgNum))
  tPage.Refresh()
end sub

Comment: @LarsTech code also 100% works:  tabPage2.ScrollControlIntoView(tabPage2.Controls.Item("pic_" & imgNum))

Comment: @IbnAdam I still experience some problems with your implementation, but thanks anyway. I implemented LarsTech's code and I mentioned it in the comment next to his.